# Fatal error "compatible with PDO::query" in new PHP8

Tags: php

I have a Sql class that was working perfectly fine until PHP7.
Now, using PHP8, I get the error shown below.

**Fatal error: Declaration of DB\Sql::query($query, $parameters = []) must be compatible with PDO::query(string $query, ?int $fetchMode = null, mixed ...$fetchModeArgs) in C:\xampp\page\class\DB\Sql.php on line 15**

Nothing has changed in the code!But I really can't understand what's wrong!

My Sql class has a "query" function like this (line 15)

```
public function query($query, $parameters=array()) {
    $statement = $this->conection->prepare($query);
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
            $statement->bindValue($key,$value);
        }
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement;
}
```

The "$this->conection calls this:

```
private $conection;

public function __construct() {
    $this->conection = new PDO("mysql:host=".dbHost.";dbname=".dbDb,dbUsuario,dbSenha);
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove "query" and use "run" instead.

Comment: Is this because "query" is a default function and "run" is not? Won't "run" throw exceptions in the future? Of course, hard to say what happens in the future, but is it likely?